# Pagination of insights results in Facebook

Tags: python, json, facebook-graph-api

I'm making requests to FB API, retriving data from a FB page.

I have a dict with params like this, just get data from 08-01 to 08-20:

```py
data_test = {
    
    'page_likes' :    {'page_id': '111',
                       'metric': 'page_fans',
                       'since': datetime(2019, 8, 1, 0, 0, 0),
                       'until': datetime(2019, 8, 20, 0, 0, 0),
                       'date_preset' : 'yesterday',
                       'period': 'day'},
    'page_impressions' : {'page_id': '111',
                       'metric': 'page_impressions',
                       'since': datetime(2019, 8, 1, 0, 0, 0),
                       'until': datetime(2019, 8, 20, 0, 0, 0),
                       'date_preset' : 'yesterday',
                       'period': 'day'}
}
```

And run a loop through it, collecting raw data to a list, then checking for additional pages, and adding to the list.

```py
responses_time_balanced = [] # list for responses

# loop through data_test

for k, v in data_test.items():
    sample_request = graph.get_connections(id = v['page_id'],
                                          connection_name='insights',
                                          metric = v['metric'],
                                          since = v['since'],
                                          until = v['until'],
                                          #date_preset = v['date_preset'],
                                          period = v['period'])
    
    # add responses to the responses_time_balanced 
    responses_time_balanced.append(sample_request)
   
    # check for additinal pages and add data from them to the list
    for request in responses_time_balanced:
        if 'next' in request['paging'].keys():
            request = requests.get(request['paging']['next']).json()
            responses_time_balanced.append(request)
```

But for some reasons, which I can't get, data from the second page duplicates.

So the final list looks like this:

Data:

1. page_fans from 2019-08-02 to 2019-08-19
2. page_fans from 2019-08-20 to 2019-09-06
3. page_impressions from 2019-08-02 to 2019-08-19
4. page_impressions from 2019-08-20 to 2019-09-06

and again

5. page_fans from 2019-08-20 to 2019-09-06
6. page_impressions from 2019-08-20 to 2019-09-06

There is some stupid mistake in the code, but i can't get it

The whole response:
the access token is not valid

```
[{'data': [{'name': 'page_fans',
    'period': 'day',
    'values': [{'value': 113264, 'end_time': '2019-08-02T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 113246, 'end_time': '2019-08-03T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 113231, 'end_time': '2019-08-04T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 113219, 'end_time': '2019-08-05T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 113195, 'end_time': '2019-08-06T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 113177, 'end_time': '2019-08-07T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 113166, 'end_time': '2019-08-08T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 113147, 'end_time': '2019-08-09T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 113138, 'end_time': '2019-08-10T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 113132, 'end_time': '2019-08-11T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 113124, 'end_time': '2019-08-12T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 113118, 'end_time': '2019-08-13T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 113109, 'end_time': '2019-08-14T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 113097, 'end_time': '2019-08-15T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 113091, 'end_time': '2019-08-16T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 113082, 'end_time': '2019-08-17T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 113071, 'end_time': '2019-08-18T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 113066, 'end_time': '2019-08-19T07:00:00+0000'}],
    'title': 'Lifetime Total Likes',
    'description': 'Lifetime: The total number of people who have liked your Page. (Unique Users)',
    'id': '571653679838052/insights/page_fans/day'}],
  'paging': {'previous': 'https://graph.facebook.com/v4.0/571653679838052/insights?access_token=EAAHzAoOZCOJQBALIh8wCto7ZCsRMTvs4ybK8I0pH1xQ4YKgfbdsOeLwxgFcJZAYDqGxgofdZBlzmqZBH1tHY5QgAH7KHUAhAjVg5lw9psgOysZAzGEVZBZBE1cVPdqZCJneS1ousyt0xZCx1kPexvSvVQ9tK783bpp9PtJZACvjgqUCRL5LC0IuhmB1&since=1563087600&until=1564642800&metric=page_fans&period=day',
   'next': 'https://graph.facebook.com/v4.0/571653679838052/insights?access_token=EAAHzAoOZCOJQBALIh8wCto7ZCsRMTvs4ybK8I0pH1xQ4YKgfbdsOeLwxgFcJZAYDqGxgofdZBlzmqZBH1tHY5QgAH7KHUAhAjVg5lw9psgOysZAzGEVZBZBE1cVPdqZCJneS1ousyt0xZCx1kPexvSvVQ9tK783bpp9PtJZACvjgqUCRL5LC0IuhmB1&since=1566198000&until=1567753200&metric=page_fans&period=day'}},
 {'data': [{'name': 'page_fans',
    'period': 'day',
    'values': [{'value': 113209, 'end_time': '2019-08-20T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 113299, 'end_time': '2019-08-21T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 113352, 'end_time': '2019-08-22T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 113409, 'end_time': '2019-08-23T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 113469, 'end_time': '2019-08-24T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 113517, 'end_time': '2019-08-25T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 113578, 'end_time': '2019-08-26T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 113622, 'end_time': '2019-08-27T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 113652, 'end_time': '2019-08-28T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 113700, 'end_time': '2019-08-29T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 113723, 'end_time': '2019-08-30T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 113756, 'end_time': '2019-08-31T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 113792, 'end_time': '2019-09-01T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 113839, 'end_time': '2019-09-02T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 113873, 'end_time': '2019-09-03T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 113911, 'end_time': '2019-09-04T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 113913, 'end_time': '2019-09-05T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 113913, 'end_time': '2019-09-06T07:00:00+0000'}],
    'title': 'Lifetime Total Likes',
    'description': 'Lifetime: The total number of people who have liked your Page. (Unique Users)',
    'id': '571653679838052/insights/page_fans/day'}],
  'paging': {'previous': 'https://graph.facebook.com/v4.0/571653679838052/insights?access_token=EAAHzAoOZCOJQBALIh8wCto7ZCsRMTvs4ybK8I0pH1xQ4YKgfbdsOeLwxgFcJZAYDqGxgofdZBlzmqZBH1tHY5QgAH7KHUAhAjVg5lw9psgOysZAzGEVZBZBE1cVPdqZCJneS1ousyt0xZCx1kPexvSvVQ9tK783bpp9PtJZACvjgqUCRL5LC0IuhmB1&since=1564642800&until=1566198000&metric=page_fans&period=day'}},
 {'data': [{'name': 'page_impressions',
    'period': 'day',
    'values': [{'value': 1467, 'end_time': '2019-08-02T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 421, 'end_time': '2019-08-03T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 271, 'end_time': '2019-08-04T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 260, 'end_time': '2019-08-05T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 1584, 'end_time': '2019-08-06T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 484, 'end_time': '2019-08-07T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 269, 'end_time': '2019-08-08T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 1290, 'end_time': '2019-08-09T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 487, 'end_time': '2019-08-10T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 205, 'end_time': '2019-08-11T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 267, 'end_time': '2019-08-12T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 267, 'end_time': '2019-08-13T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 233, 'end_time': '2019-08-14T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 388, 'end_time': '2019-08-15T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 1383, 'end_time': '2019-08-16T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 583, 'end_time': '2019-08-17T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 12554, 'end_time': '2019-08-18T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 258, 'end_time': '2019-08-19T07:00:00+0000'}],
    'title': 'Daily Total Impressions',
    'description': "Daily: The number of times any content from your Page or about your Page entered a person's screen. This includes posts, stories, check-ins, ads, social information from people who interact with your Page and more. (Total Count)",
    'id': '571653679838052/insights/page_impressions/day'}],
  'paging': {'previous': 'https://graph.facebook.com/v4.0/571653679838052/insights?access_token=EAAHzAoOZCOJQBALIh8wCto7ZCsRMTvs4ybK8I0pH1xQ4YKgfbdsOeLwxgFcJZAYDqGxgofdZBlzmqZBH1tHY5QgAH7KHUAhAjVg5lw9psgOysZAzGEVZBZBE1cVPdqZCJneS1ousyt0xZCx1kPexvSvVQ9tK783bpp9PtJZACvjgqUCRL5LC0IuhmB1&since=1563087600&until=1564642800&metric=page_impressions&period=day',
   'next': 'https://graph.facebook.com/v4.0/571653679838052/insights?access_token=EAAHzAoOZCOJQBALIh8wCto7ZCsRMTvs4ybK8I0pH1xQ4YKgfbdsOeLwxgFcJZAYDqGxgofdZBlzmqZBH1tHY5QgAH7KHUAhAjVg5lw9psgOysZAzGEVZBZBE1cVPdqZCJneS1ousyt0xZCx1kPexvSvVQ9tK783bpp9PtJZACvjgqUCRL5LC0IuhmB1&since=1566198000&until=1567753200&metric=page_impressions&period=day'}},
 {'data': [{'name': 'page_fans',
    'period': 'day',
    'values': [{'value': 113209, 'end_time': '2019-08-20T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 113299, 'end_time': '2019-08-21T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 113352, 'end_time': '2019-08-22T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 113409, 'end_time': '2019-08-23T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 113469, 'end_time': '2019-08-24T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 113517, 'end_time': '2019-08-25T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 113578, 'end_time': '2019-08-26T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 113622, 'end_time': '2019-08-27T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 113652, 'end_time': '2019-08-28T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 113700, 'end_time': '2019-08-29T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 113723, 'end_time': '2019-08-30T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 113756, 'end_time': '2019-08-31T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 113792, 'end_time': '2019-09-01T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 113839, 'end_time': '2019-09-02T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 113873, 'end_time': '2019-09-03T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 113911, 'end_time': '2019-09-04T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 113913, 'end_time': '2019-09-05T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 113913, 'end_time': '2019-09-06T07:00:00+0000'}],
    'title': 'Lifetime Total Likes',
    'description': 'Lifetime: The total number of people who have liked your Page. (Unique Users)',
    'id': '571653679838052/insights/page_fans/day'}],
  'paging': {'previous': 'https://graph.facebook.com/v4.0/571653679838052/insights?access_token=EAAHzAoOZCOJQBALIh8wCto7ZCsRMTvs4ybK8I0pH1xQ4YKgfbdsOeLwxgFcJZAYDqGxgofdZBlzmqZBH1tHY5QgAH7KHUAhAjVg5lw9psgOysZAzGEVZBZBE1cVPdqZCJneS1ousyt0xZCx1kPexvSvVQ9tK783bpp9PtJZACvjgqUCRL5LC0IuhmB1&since=1564642800&until=1566198000&metric=page_fans&period=day'}},
 {'data': [{'name': 'page_impressions',
    'period': 'day',
    'values': [{'value': 53579, 'end_time': '2019-08-20T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 36032, 'end_time': '2019-08-21T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 33509, 'end_time': '2019-08-22T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 41100, 'end_time': '2019-08-23T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 39801, 'end_time': '2019-08-24T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 38691, 'end_time': '2019-08-25T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 37131, 'end_time': '2019-08-26T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 28139, 'end_time': '2019-08-27T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 17064, 'end_time': '2019-08-28T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 16537, 'end_time': '2019-08-29T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 20000, 'end_time': '2019-08-30T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 18023, 'end_time': '2019-08-31T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 15622, 'end_time': '2019-09-01T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 27015, 'end_time': '2019-09-02T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 25329, 'end_time': '2019-09-03T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 18049, 'end_time': '2019-09-04T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 1124, 'end_time': '2019-09-05T07:00:00+0000'},
     {'value': 0, 'end_time': '2019-09-06T07:00:00+0000'}],
    'title': 'Daily Total Impressions',
    'description': "Daily: The number of times any content from your Page or about your Page entered a person's screen. This includes posts, stories, check-ins, ads, social information from people who interact with your Page and more. (Total Count)",
    'id': '571653679838052/insights/page_impressions/day'}],
  'paging': {'previous': 'https://graph.facebook.com/v4.0/571653679838052/insights?access_token=EAAHzAoOZCOJQBALIh8wCto7ZCsRMTvs4ybK8I0pH1xQ4YKgfbdsOeLwxgFcJZAYDqGxgofdZBlzmqZBH1tHY5QgAH7KHUAhAjVg5lw9psgOysZAzGEVZBZBE1cVPdqZCJneS1ousyt0xZCx1kPexvSvVQ9tK783bpp9PtJZACvjgqUCRL5LC0IuhmB1&since=1564642800&until=1566198000&metric=page_impressions&period=day'}}]
```

## update

checked with the Graph API Explorer, there is everything ok

Comment: I’d check if you get the same result, if you make the request in Graph API Explorer, and follow the pagination links in there. If so, this is probably a case for a bug report, https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs